# Unzip files in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unzip, ssziparchive

How to go about unzipping a file in swift? In Objective-C, I used SSZipArchive and I loved it. As seen in the code below. I suspect if I decide to keep SSZipArchive, [I will have to bridge an Objective-C file to my Swift file.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_76) Is there any updated third-party, or better yet Apple-Documentation to unzip a file in Swift?

```
NSString *zipPath = [self.globalFileStrucure stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"zipfile.zip"];

[data writeToFile:zipPath options:0 error:&error];

BOOL unZipped = 0;

unZipped = [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:self.globalFileStrucure];
```

Comment: [`pod 'SSZipArchive'`](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SSZipArchive) is fully compatible with Swift.

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 2 (Update):**

So it works for me without Errors:

1. download/clone the Library here: [ssziparchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive)
2. copy the Directory "SSZipArchive" to your Project (Drag&Drop) and select 'Create groups'
3. include the library to your Project Swift-ObjC Bridge (xxxx-Bridge-Header.h)

   #import "SSZipArchive.h"
4. link the Library "libz.tbd" - Part of iOS

   (Project -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> +)
5. Ready to zip/unzip

Comment: I'm using a cocoapod to add in SSZipArchive, and I'm getting errors on all the gzip references. I added libz.dylib to the target of both the pod and the project but still having errors. Any ideas? @screenworker

Comment: For Xcode 7 and Swift 2 & Mac apps, import 2 libs, libz.tbd and dylib1.o

Answer (score 2):

If you're using any of UIKit or AppKit, you're already working with a Swift-ObjC bridge. Don't worry about that, just use the library you know and love!

```
let zipPath = globalFileStrucure.stringByAppendingPathComponent("zipfile.zip")
data.writeToFile(zipPath, options: nil, error: &error)

let unZipped = SSZipArchive.unzipFileAtPath(zipPath, toDestination: globalFileStrucure)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found WPZipArchive is more easy to use and install, using Cocoapods. Anyone who interested can read the guide below:

1) Open Terminal.app from your Mac Application/Utilities folder or from your Launchpad

2) Enter `sudo gem update --system` into your Terminal to ensure your Ruby is up to date

3) Enter `sudo gem install cocoapods` to install cocoapods (This process will likely take a few minutes, just wait it show Completed)

4) Enter `pod setup` to setup the cocoapods (from here onward, you do not need to use `sudo` command, use only `pod`)

5) Launch Xcode and create a new project (If you do not have existing project created). Skip this step if you had a Xcode project created.

6) QUIT Xcode program. Yes, close your project and quit the Xcode program

7) Back to Terminal and enter `cd Path/To/Folder/Containing/YourProject` replace this Path/To/Folder/Containing/YourProject with your own directory path

8) Enter `pod init`

9) Enter `open -a Xcode Podfile` to open the podfile using Xcode program. The default Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :osx, '10.10'
use_frameworks!

target 'myprojectname' do
pod 'WPZipArchive', '0.0.1'
end
```

`platform :osx, '10.10'` is specify the minimum deployment target, you can change to whatever you preferred.

10) Save and Close Podfile (Close Xcode too)

11) Back to Terminal and enter `pod install` this is to install the WPZipArchive, this will take few minutes.

12) You are done installing WPZipArchive.

Launch Xcode Project:

**IMPORTANT**: From now on, you must launch your Xcode project using the **.xcworkspace** NOT .xcodeproj

On the ViewController.swift or any .swift file you want to use zip or unzip method, just add import WPZipArchive like below:

```
import Cocoa
import WPZipArchive
```

To Zip a file, call method like this:

```
WPZipArchive.createZipFileAtPath(zipPath, withContentsOfDirectory: sampleDataPath)
```

To Unzip a file, call method like this:

```
WPZipArchive.unzipFileAtPath(zipPath, toDestination: unzipPath)
```

That's all and it work and easy to implement.

Enjoy zipping and unzipping

Answer (score 0):

@screenworker (Unome) asked about a rash of errors that all make reference to the libz framework. I ran into something similar. The link step produced errors concerning "symbols" such as "_crc32". All these symbols could be found in the libz.tbd stub.

The issue in this case is that I had mistakenly added the libz.tbd reference to the Test target, not the Target named for the project itself. This can be checked by going to the Build Phases display:

- In the Project Navigator (left panel) click on your project name
- In the editor, click on the "Build Phases" tab.
- In the Build Phases display, look for a list entitled Targets in a narrow column adjacent to the Project Navigator
- Click on the target that is the same as your project (e.g. myProject and not myProjectTest or myProjectUITest)
- If the arrow beside "Link Binary With Libraries" is clicked you should see the list of libraries - which should in include libz.