# Swift How to Unzip file from URL with Alamofire and SSZipArchive

Tags: ios, swift, ssziparchive

```
 func downLoad(fileName:String) {
        let urlString : String = "\(myurl)\(fileName)"
        var localPath: NSURL?
        let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)

    Alamofire.download(urlString, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, to: destination)
        .downloadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)) { progress in
            print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        }
        .validate { request, response, temporaryURL, destinationURL in
            // Custom evaluation closure now includes file URLs (allows you to parse out error messages if necessary)
            return .success
        }
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
            print(response.destinationURL?.path)
            print(response.destinationURL?.absoluteString)
            let unzipDirectory = self.unzipPath(fileURL:fileName)

            let success = SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: (response.destinationURL?.path)!, toDestination: unzipDirectory!)
            print(success)
            if !success {
                return
            }


    }
}


func unzipPath(fileName:String) -> String? {
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let pathComponent = url.appendingPathComponent("test\(fileName)")
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: pathComponent!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
        return pathComponent?.absoluteString
    }
```

i get right path in  `response.destinationURL`

but success is false

i tried `atPath :`  to `response.destinationURL?.path` and

```
response.destinationURL?.absoluteString
```

but failed too

What i am doing wrong

`destinationURL?.path` return this

```
Optional("/Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3FBAD207-E5AB-4FC1-8199-2269A1249D97/data/Containers/Data/Application/CB1C2EF5-3100-430B-B869-774C09B8EA7F/Documents/testFile.zip")


response.destinationURL?.absoluteString
```

return this

```
Optional("file:///Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3FBAD207-E5AB-4FC1-8199-2269A1249D97/data/Containers/Data/Application/CB1C2EF5-3100-430B-B869-774C09B8EA7F/Documents/testFile.zip")
```

i think this is correct URL

why failed unzip?

Comment: try this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033759/unzip-nsdata-folder-from-url-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your code, the path you are using for the source is perfect.

For the destination path, try updating it to

```
func unzipPath(fileName:String) -> String? {
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let pathWithComponent = path.appendingPathComponent("test\(fileName)")
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: pathWithComponent, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
    return pathWithComponent
}
```

Try and share the results.

Comment: I have already downloaded testFile.zip When the code has error. after delete 
install this is worked

Comment: right, if zip already exits, it should be removed before downloading. Great it worked.