# How can i unzip .tar.gz file in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Newb here. I want to unzip a .tar.gz file in swift. I know how to unzip a file with one extension. Now please tell me how can i unzip this file. Do i need to perform unzip two times or any other option is there in swift??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: a is your file name .tar .gz is extension?

Comment: https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unzip files in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654194/unzip-files-in-swift)

Comment: @Darji Jigar...no file is having an extension of .tar.gz

Comment: @gaurav Dave...Please read both question again!! I am asking how to unzip a file with two extension. I know how to unzip a simple zip file with one extension!!!

Comment: @KKb replace black character in last extension

Comment: @darji.. i am sorry, what does that mean?

Comment: What type of OS now your are using? Linux or MAC.